# Get Info from EXCEPTION_RECORD

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, exception

If I catch an access violation with SEH, how can I get address of violation ? [GetExceptionInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679357%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) gives me [LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that contains

- ExceptionRecord - A pointer to an EXCEPTION_RECORD structure that
  contains a machine-independent description of the exception.
- ContextRecord - A pointer to a CONTEXT structure that contains a
  processor-specific description of the state of the processor at the time of the exception.

How can i get this info this without writing a dump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory address as well as type of operation is contained in ExceptionInformation field inside ExceptionRecord structur. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363082%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

**ExceptionInformation**
An array of additional arguments that describe the exception. The RaiseException function can specify this array of arguments. For most exception codes, the array elements are undefined. The following table describes the exception codes whose array elements are defined.

**Exception code Meaning**
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
*The first element of the array* contains a read-write flag that indicates the type of operation that caused the access violation. If this value is zero, the thread attempted to read the inaccessible data. If this value is 1, the thread attempted to write to an inaccessible address. If this value is 8, the thread causes a user-mode data execution prevention (DEP) violation.

*The second array element* specifies the virtual address of the inaccessible data.

Answer (score 2):

The [`EXCEPTION_RECORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363082.aspx) structure has an `ExceptionAddress` field.